# Mac tool for editing pspicture

Tags: pstricks, live-preview

I've used TikZ Editor for some time to make my TikZ drawings. I've really appreciated the live-rendering features. Now, I'm wanting to make some graphics using the `pst-optexp` package, and I'm having a hard time finding an application that does what TikZ Editor does for pstricks. Theoretically, TikZ editor should do the trick... it allows me to change everything in the preamble, etc... except for allowing me to change the `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Does anyone know of a way to:

1. Install software that allows live-reload of `pspicture` environment?
2. Modify the code in TikZ Editor such that I can compile `pspicture` in this application?

For the record, I'm running OS X El Capitan. I'm thankful for the link to the other stack exchange question with a list of apps that people use for editing. However, most of those are either click-and-drag, or are for windows/linux. I'm not interested in a click-and-drag application. I'm more interested in something very similar to TikZ Editor. **Is there any such editor that allows live preview of PSTricks on Mac?**

Comment: Perhaps it's just that pst-optexp takes a long time to compile. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Nevertheless the other question is OS independent and therefore also valid for OS X. As soon as you have enough reputation you can push that question and even give it a bounty.